# Covers of bouquets of circles with deck groups isomorphic to given finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

When given a bouquet of circles, say the bouquet of two circles, if asked to draw the cover of that space with automorphism group corresponding to a given finite group, say $S3$, what is the general procedure to follow?

Comment: It's a little difficult to understand the question. Couldn't you give an example ?

Comment: For example, how would you construct a regular cover of the wedge of 2 circles with automorphism group $D_{10}$ (the dihedral group of order 10).

I'm sort of confused on where even to start, to be honest. I thought maybe constructing the Cayley Graph of $D_{10}$, but then I'm not sure how to relate that back to the wedge of two circles.

Comment: What are you calling the "regular cover" of the "wedge" of 2 circles ? I don't understand the two terms between quotes in this context. You should refer to a figure !

Comment: "Regular cover" meaning "normal cover" i.e. a covering map $p:\tilde{X} \rightarrow X$ where the image of the induced homomorphism, $p_*$ is a normal subgroup of the fundamental group of $X$ (or alternatively the group of automorphisms of the covering space acts transitively on $p^{-1}(x)$ for any $x$ in $X$)

Wedge of two circles means two unit circles with the basepoint associated, so like a figure of eight.

Comment: Thank you. I just had a look [here](https://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Wedge_of_two_circles) too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an outline of the general procedure.

Step 1: Apply the theorem that the degree of a regular covering map is equal to the order of the automorphism group of the covering space (this is a corollary of the theorem that the automorphism group acts freely and transitively on each of its orbits).

Therefore, the degree is equal to the order of $S_3$, which is $6$.

Step 2: In the base space --- namely, the wedge of two circles --- there is just $1$ vertex. So, the covering space will have $6$ vertices, each covering that $1$ vertex of the base space. Not only that, but the action of the automorphism group on those 6 vertices is transitive.

Step 3: Pick your favorite transitive action of $S_3$ on a set of $6$ elements; we can then take those $6$ elements to be the vertices of the covering space.

Step 3:  In the wedge of two circles, name the two circles $A$ and $B$. You must now attach six $A$ edges and six $B$ edges up in the covering space, picking attachments that are invariant under the action of the automorphism group.

Done!